# What's the difference between delta and primary delta in GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
    var dy = details.delta.dy;
    var primaryDy = details.primaryDelta;
  },
)
```

I couldn't find out the difference between a regular delta and a primary, both seems to do the same job. Can anyone explain the difference between these two deltas? (As usual Docs are not very clear, at least to me)

Comment: Offset delta: The amount the pointer has moved in the coordinate space of the event receiver since the previous update..
double primaryDelta: The amount the pointer has moved along the primary axis in the coordinate space of the event receiver since the previous update..

Comment: docs say: "If the GestureDragUpdateCallback is for a one-dimensional drag (e.g., a horizontal or vertical drag), then this value contains the component of **delta** along the primary axis (e.g., horizontal or vertical, respectively)" - so yes it is the same as `delta.dx / dy` for horizontal / vertical drag callbacks

Comment: Looks like any-movement vs. primary-axis-movement. See: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-gesturedetector-examples#TapUpDetails

Comment: @pskink Thank you sir, this is what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

**[DragUpdateDetailsclass:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html)**

> delta → Offset The amount the pointer has moved in the coordinate
> space of the event receiver since the previous update

Meaning, The distance covered by dragging since the last pointer contact. `Delta gives dx for horizontal distance and dy for vertical distance.`

> primaryDelta → double The amount the pointer has moved along the
> primary axis in the coordinate space of the event receiver since the
> previous update

`primaryDelta gives the absolute distance in only one primary direction` of dragging, meaning if the drag is primarily in horizontal axis(GestureDragUpdateCallback + Horizontal only) then this value represents the drag distance in the horizontal axis. If the drag in is vertical axis (GestureDragUpdateCallback + Vertical only) then this value represents the drag amount in the vertical axis.

Note: if the GestureDragUpdateCallback is for a two-dimensional drag (e.g., a pan), then this value is null.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but there's no such thing like `absolute distance` when it comes to dragging. A primary delta indeed is a regular delta for a specific drag. For instance, if the drag is vertical, primary delta and a regular delta given by `delta.dy` give you the same value and the same thing applies for a horizontal drag.